# Material SnackBar extraClasses doesn't seem to be working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Hello Stack Overflow friends!!!!

I am trying to implement the [material snackbar component](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview).  I am able to get the snackbar to appear but don't seem to be able to get the config properties to make any real difference.

Here's the code from my **snack-bar.component.ts** file:

```
openSnackBar(message: string, action: string, type:string){
    let config = new MdSnackBarConfig();
    config.duration = 500000;
    config.direction="rtl";
    config.politeness="assertive";

    if(type == 'Error')
    config.extraClasses=['mat-simple-snackbar','mat-simple-snackbar-action'];
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, config);
  }
```

The only **config** property that seems to do anything is **duration**.

My main stumbling block is two-fold: First:  I am struggling implement the extraClasses property.  I've tried passing existing snack-bar classes in order to overwrite them, and I've also tried passing in new classes.  Second: How is this supposed to work?  Should the class reside in the corresponding **snack-bar.component.css** file?

What I would really like is a comprehensive example of how this works.  The one on the material site doesn't implement this property so it's not helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your **First** question:

You need to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component for `config.extraClasses` to take effect. Read about [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer to your **Second** question: **Yes,** the classes should be in your `snack-bar.component.css` file.

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lbhxdt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks @Faisal!  It definitely looks like it works.  But that said, when I inspect the snackbar, I don't see the .extra-class coming up under styles in Chrome.  Should it not come up?

Comment: @kickinchicken It does come up, please see the `<snack-bar-container>` tag. Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: Mine isn't coming up, but yours is.  I just wanted to make sure before I marked it as answered.  Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why the class is appearing in the snack-bar-container classes but not coming up as a css class?

Comment: They are added, not sure why you are not able to see

Answer (score 2):

Below configuration is working for me.

**Versions**
Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Angular: 6.0.2
Material: 6.0.2

**Step 1**: Add style in ***src/styles.css***

```
.snack-color{
    background-color:purple;
}
```

**Step 2**: Add panelClass in openSnackBar() function

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
import { InformationComponent } from '../header/information/information.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent  {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

 openSnackBar() {

    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(InformationComponent, {
      duration: 5000,
      **panelClass: ['snack-color']**
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with angular material ? they always change syntaxes :|